How to Prevent Prettier from Formatting C++ Macros into a Single Line?
I'm encountering an issue where Prettier automatically reformats my C++ macros into a single line, even though I've tried using the // prettier-ignore directive. Here's an example of my code:
`// Expected formatting
#define vo(a)             \
    for (auto x : a)      \
    {                     \
        cout << x << " "; \
    }                     \
    cout << endl;`

However, Prettier reformats it into a single line:
#define vo(a) for(auto x:a){cout<<x<<" ";}cout<<endl;

What I've Tried:

Placing // prettier-ignore before the macro definition.
Checking my Prettier configuration file (.prettierrc) for any settings that might override the ignore directive.
Using a .prettierignore file to exclude the specific file.
Despite these efforts, Prettier continues to reformat the macro. I want to preserve the multi-line structure for readability and maintainability.

Questions:

How can I prevent Prettier from reformatting my C++ macros into a single line?
Is there a configuration or setting in Prettier or my editor that I might miss?


I would write a function instead of a macro. You rarely need macros in modern C++

It is code formatter focused to format everything javascript, css, html and such. Jack of all trades is often master of none. If it can't do something that you want then consider other, more specialised tools ... like clang-format , artistic style or uncrustify.

I'd spell that template <std::ranges::range Range> std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Range&& range), not #define vo(a)

@ÖöTiib I'd call this particular behaviour a feature, not a bug, of prettier. It should make good code pretty and bad code ugly, and it does.

@Caleth I do not understand your point. The macro in question is indeed better to write as a function but the tool does neither detect that nor refactor it into function just obfuscates.  Majority of meaningful and mature C++ code bases contain some multi-line macros and plain uglification of those is unhelpful. Some people are masochists but not everybody.

@ÖöTiib because macros behave "almost, but not quite" like functions, they should be changed into functions, for safety. A tool making them ugly helps prioritise that.

@caleth But how that tool helps? It does not identify macros that can be refactored to functions and it does not transform these into form that is easier to refactor. So it did nothing of value.

@ÖöTiib it brought the macro to the attention of a human

@Caleth in unhelpful manner. Also it is usually false positive in real non-novice code base. Exactly same reason why static code analysers are not that popular. Being unhelpful and giving too lot of false positives.

@ÖöTiib OP's macro is not a false positive for "should be a function". Once static reflection comes in C++26, there isn't any situation where a macro pretending to be a function is warranted, the only thing left is stringifying tokens. Static analysers are popular

@Caleth Future helps no one as they would need time machine to use C++26 compiler. Also migration takes often decade. Who can tell if our civilisation even lasts until 2036? Static analysers are unpopular considering scarcity of configuration settings for such or cases of running those in CI of useful code bases.

@ÖöTiib read what I said: The only current situations where macros do something that functions can't (yet!) is stringifying tokens. All other uses that in the past macros were needed for have gotten language or library support to do equivalent things in functions. Which is unrelated to OP's code, it was never one of those cases, it should be a function when targeting C++98.

As far as I can tell, Prettier does not support C++ (q.v. docs).  How are you running Prettier against your C++ code?

@Caleth maybe you read yourself what you wrote. You said that the behaviour is good feature because it draws human attention to a part of code by making it ugly. Stringifying tokens or parts of code is red herring, macros are more commonly used for portability, optional usage of extensions by compiler, achitecture support or other tools and for reporting source code file, source code line and function where some situation was detected.

@ÖöTiib I'm not talking about macros that are tested in #if or #ifdef, but macro's like OP's that are "pretend functions". Source locations are now doable with std::source_location
